# No module named myapp

Tags: python, django, static-analysis, pylint

I have this project directory structure:

```
.
.pylintrc
|--myproj   .
            |--myapp
            |--myproj (settings.py is here)
            __init__.py
            manage.py
            .
```

In settings.py, INSTALLED_APPS I have the first entry `'myapp'`.

From the root folder (containing .pylintrc), I call

```
$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproj.myproj.settings pylint myproj --load-plugins pylint_django
```

However, I get error `no module named 'myapp'`. If I change the INSTALLED_APPS entry to `'myproj.myapp'`, then it is able to continue, but now I'm unable to start the project normally with `manage.py runserver`.

[pastebin myproj.settings](https://pastebin.com/raw/tz0V52xb)

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to proceed?

Comment: Can you share your settings.py file?

Comment: @Daniel see update answer with link

Comment: See my answer below:

Answer (score 0):

Likely your settings.py is improperly configured, you need to do something like this:

**settings.py**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
    ...
]
```

If you open the apps.py file in your myapp directory you'll see the config class that should be included in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: If I do this, I get error `ImportError: Module 'myproj.myapp' does not contain a 'MyappConfig' class.`.

I've recreated a fresh project with django-admin startproject just now for this question, so everything is default except for the app `myapp` and added entry in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

One last change I have also done is to add a file __init__.py in the first `myproj` directory, as shown in the folder structure, is it possible it's a problem?

Comment: The pattern is `<app-name>.app.<config-class>` - you should not include the project name in the string in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Right, my apologies. I've changed it to `myapp.apps.MyappConfig`, but now I'm back to the same error as in the original question, `no module named 'myapp'`. Can it have something to do with the working directory from which pylint runs?

Comment: The string is case sensitive - are you sure you have "myapp" spelled correctly with proper casing? It needs to match exactly the name of your "myapp" directory.

Comment: Yes, because I can run it fine with manage.py runserver.

Comment: Then - yes - likely something wrong with pylint - apologies I cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me and I find my solution.

In My Case, I missed my urls.py file.

```
re_path(r"^chaining/", include("smart_selects.urls")),
```

to

```
re_path(r"^chaining/", include("packages.smart_selects.urls")),
```